# Can the Pyramid framework be run on a CGI server

Tags: python, cgi, pyramid

Ok, I get that CGI is sow outdated, and no one likes it, but I have a customer who needs a new site, is on shared hosting, and does not wish to change hosting providers. We are doing the back-end of his site in Python, and are researching Python framework options that can run as CGI(no one wants to just use the CGI module). So far, It seems Django can be run on CGI, but it is terrible. Flask and Bottle seem to run well on CGI(at least it is supported), but I was wondering if the Pyramid Framework can. If not, I guess we will just be using Flask. Can I get Pyramid running on CGI? If so what would be the performance against running Flask r Bottle under CGI?

Comment: A VPS capable of running Pyramid start from $5/mo... I'm wondering how many _years_ of VPS hosting could've been paid for with the funds allocated by your client to evaluation of running various Python frameworks on CGI :)

Comment: @Sergey sometimes you are stuck in old infrastructure. It's different when you are deploying something greenfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this solution here, it shows how to use WSGI on CGI
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#the-server-gateway-side

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at wsgiref as well
https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html

example :
https://github.com/w1mvy/twitter_bot_on_gae-py/blob/55754d0ec1580b67f7f0c710f5cf3456313cff4d/app.py